# Caching with Apache Mod Redirect

Tags: regex, apache, caching, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

So I want to keep all my cached pages in a folder called 
/cache

and I was thinking to have the generic url

```
example.com/not a real folder
```

silently redirect to

```
example.com/cache/not-a-real-folder.html
```

and if the above file does not exist have it redirect to

```
index.php?page=not a real folder
```

**but how do I design the Apache Mod Rewrite code that will do all this, is it even possible?**

I'm new to these things so any help would be greatly appreciated!
Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
# First check if the file requested exists in the cache folder,
# if it does, rewrite the url to the cached version
# -The %{REQUEST_URI} will probably start with a '/'
RewriteCond /cache%{REQUEST_URI} -f
RewriteRule (.*) /cache$1.html [L,NC]

# If the request makes it here, the file requested is not in the cache,
# so we can rewrite the request to the index.php page for processing
RewriteRule (.*) /index.php?page=$1 [L]
```

For clairification, are your requests coming in with spaces, and you need them rewritten with dashes? Because that adds some more complexity...

Hope this helps.

Comment: Hi, thank you for your response! I haven't tested this out yet but it looks really good, and i think it should work. Well my requests will not have spaces but I would like the script to work even if they did in the future. Thank you!